# Angularjs Controller Called Twice?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, fancybox

I have called the data from server using `ngResource`. however, i have figured out that for some reason, my controller is called twice. 
Here is my code;

App.js file

```
// declare a module
var blogApp = angular.module('blogApp', ['ngResource']);
```

HomeController.js file;

```
blogApp.controller("HomeController", function ($scope, $resource) {
    var HotNews = $resource('/api/article/hotnews?culture=en-US');
    $scope.news = HotNews.query();
    alert("hello"); //here i see hello alert box two times
});
```

my view;

```
  <ul id="news" data-ng-controller="HomeController">
      <li data-ng-repeat="headline in news">
          {{headline.description}}
          <a href="#" title="Read More">» more</a>
      </li>
  </ul>
```

**Updated:** the issue is in `fancybox.js` file that is in main layout;

```
<html data-ng-app="blogApp">
```

the source files are;

```
    <!-- JS -->
<script src="/Content/scripts/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/scripts/lib/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/scripts/app/app.js"></script>
<script src="/Content/scripts/app/controllers/HomeController.js"></script>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script src="/content/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
```

**when i comment out the fancybox, all works fine but when i add it back, i get two times alert box;**

Comment: do you bootstrap your app ? or do you use ng-app ? or both ?

Comment: i also updated the answer `<html data-ng-app="blogApp">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main point with this issue for me, was the way the scripts were arranged in my project. So, i comment- out each script one by one, and then i got the issue. The issue was, i was using jquery library called `pageslide`, in a situation where i have a button and when a user click on that button, the page were slide to left/right;
SO, i just move all of my `angular` related files to the end of all the scripts and now, i don't see the `alert()` box two times. 
here is the arrangement that works for me;

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    <script src="/Content/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
    <script src="/content/scripts/lib/general.js"></script>
    <script src="/content/scripts/lib/function.js"></script>
    <script src="/content/scripts/lib/styleswitch.js"></script>
    <!-- elRTE -->
    <script src="/content/scripts/lib/elrte/elrte.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="/Content/scripts/app/dataservice.js"></script>
    <script src="/Content/scripts/app/statemanager.js"></script>

    // this was causing the problem

    <script>
        $("#allpage-login-top").pageSlide({ width: "350px", direction: "left" });
        $("#allpage-signup-top").pageSlide({ width: "350px", direction: "right" });
        $("#allpage-search-top").pageSlide({ width: "350px", direction: "left", modal: true });
        $("#homepage-login-button").pageSlide({ width: "350px", direction: "left" });
        $("#homepage-signup-button").pageSlide({ width: "350px", direction: "right" });
    </script>
        <!-- JS -->
    <script src="/Content/scripts/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Content/scripts/lib/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Content/scripts/app/app.js"></script>
    <script src="/Content/scripts/app/controllers/HomeController.js"></script>

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
    @MiniProfiler.RenderIncludes()
```

Answer (score 1):

All looks ok. The problem could be elsewhere. I created a plunker based on the above and executed the controller once. You may want to modify it, add your other code if any and test it out yourself: http://embed.plnkr.co/ttvlTJBhTEd9sQUdkQjX/preview

Comment: Updated plunker with fancybox and jquery. Still worked ok. I tried 1.3.4 fancy and got some undefined msie error while loading the script so I upgraded it to the latest version. Both did load the controller only once. Maybe try upgrading your fancybox as it is now version 2.x.x.