# Controller function getting called twice using ng-show

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a very simple Angular app setup, code as follows:

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js'></script>
    <script src='app.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <div ng-show="ready()">
        Some content
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And *app.js*

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  console.log("MyCtrl called")
  $scope.ready = function() {
    console.log("ready called");
    return true;
  }
})
```

If you run this with your console open you will see *MyCtrl called* once and *ready called* twice. I have spent hours trying to figure this out, I see no reason why `$scope.ready` would be called anything but exactly one time.

If you use a Angular v1.1.5 and use `ng-if` instead of `ng-show` you will have the same behaviour, but if you use `ng-init` it correctly calls `$scope.ready` one time. In my case I will need `ng-show` or `ng-if`.

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZSwVNLeFSuhbouXZu9SM?p=preview

**Clarification:**
To elaborate on what I'm aiming for, let's say `$scope.ready` at some point later returns `false` (maybe it makes an AJAX call, that should NOT be called more than once), I would like "Some content" to no longer be visible. That is, dynamic behaviour based on the result of `$scope.ready`.

Any ideas? Thank you for the help!

For the record [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17967437/angularjs-calls-http-multiple-times-in-controller) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16874791/angulajs-controller-called-twice) are not the same problem.

Comment: `ng-init` is called in the `$compile` phase, which is only called once. Everything else is called in the `$digest` cycle, which is always called twice (though I've never figured out why).

Comment: What do you recommend then? To expand on my question, when at some point `$scope.ready` returns `false` (let's say that function calls another function), I would like "some content" to no longer be visible. E.g. dynamic behaviour Thanks

Comment: Angular is using "dirty checking" to see if the result of your $scope funtion has changed.  This is a good read: http://hueypetersen.com/posts/2013/06/17/angular_is_slow/.

Comment: @JosephSilber it is called twice because AngularJS needs to make sure a value is "stabilized" before ending the current digest cycle. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 14):

This is by design, not a bug (and it has nothing to do with the AngularJS compiler, as another answer incorrectly stated). `ng-show` and `ng-hide` work by "watching" changes of the expression `ready()`.

At each digest cycle, for every watch, AngularJS evaluates the associated expression to see if there's any change and if there is, invoking the listener (in the case of `ng-show`/`ng-hide`, the listener will show or hide the element based on the value returned by `ready()`).

Now, AngularJS can't just be satisfied with the first value returned by `ready()` because during the same digest cycle, something (e.g. another watch expression) might actually make some change that causes whatever returned by `ready()` to be a different value (e.g. by mutating an `isReady` variable which is returned by `ready()`). Obviously, developers would expect the latest value to be reflected to the DOM.

Therefore, AngularJS will evaluate every watch expression at least once to make sure that it is "stabilized" before finishing a digest cycle. Of course, this can lead to infinite digest iterations if an expression keeps changing, so AngularJS will throw an error if a digest cycle could not finish within 10 iterations.

Comment: upvoting this so that people wont skip this answer.

Answer (score 3):

There was a bug report on this, and the response was something to do with the compiler doing a *double check*

> This is expected behavior. AngularJS does the call twice to ensure that the model has stabilized before rendering it.

There should be more info on why that is here **http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler**

**Bug Report: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1146**

Comment: This neither is a bug nor has anything to do with the AngularJS compiler. That's why the Github issue was closed.

Comment: I didn't ever say it was a bug, and they recommended checking out the docs for the compiler for more information.

Comment: I'm not writing the comment for you specifically, I'm commenting for those who might read your answer and get the wrong idea that this is an issue caused by "the compiler doing a double check" (which is totally incorrect).