# AngularJs: double check in ng-show

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show

Why checks of any expression in directives like ng-show (or other) are duplicate? I made simple jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/fA5YX/. See in browser console.

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="ctrl" ng-show="test()">shown</div>
<script>
function ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.test = function() {
        console.log('check');
        return true;
    }
}
</script>
```

How make it stop? I need just one check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps linked to [Controller function getting called twice using ng-show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18581170/controller-function-getting-called-twice-using-ng-show) - to quote:

> At each digest cycle, for every watch, AngularJS evaluates the
>   associated expression to see if there's any change and if there is,
>   invoking the listener (in the case of `ng-show/ng-hide`, the listener
>   will show or hide the element based on the value returned by `ready()`).

Answer (score 1):

Every watcher is run at the digest cycle. The digest cycle is repeated until none of the results has changed value (or when angular guards against infinite loop). This is why your watchers are run multiple times. Bottom line is, don't rely on watchers being fired only once because this goes against the basic groundrules of why angular works.

If you post details on what you try to achieve we might be able to guide you to a pattern that actually works in the angular philosophy.